# Как получить доступ к переменной в своём namespace

Tags: c++

```
// vars.cpp
namespace fo {
    int value = 10;
}


// u8.cpp
#include <iostream>

extern int fo::value;

int main() {
    std::cout << fo::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Программа не компилируется, ошибка:

> ..\src\u8.cpp:4:12: error: 'fo' has not been declared

Если убрать namespace, то всё работает.

Comment: Если это какая-то глобальная константа, то, вероятно, имеет смысл определить её в хедере как `constexpr inline`.

Comment: Нет, именно как в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
namespace fo
{
    extern int value;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << fo::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор же не знает, что такое `fo`...